# How I can map image gallery inside Orchard

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am working on a web template that contain an images gallery. And when you click on an image it will open a larger image inside a slide show. this is how the image gallery looks like [link](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html)

Now I want to map this image gallery using Orchard CMS. So end-users can chose to add a picture and its slide show picture (mainly two pictures ; small one and high resolution one)? So can anyone advice how I can accomplish this inside Orchard cms ?

Comment: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Mello.ImageGallery

Comment: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.PrettyGallery

Comment: but if i want to use exactly the same image gallery that is provided by the web template http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html could this be mapped inside Orchard ?, or i can only use restricted modules provided by Orchard only?

Comment: you are pretty much restricted i'm afraid

Comment: No you are not restricted... Please look at your other similar question (asking the same question twice doesn't really help by the way) here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757267/detailed-documentation-about-mapping-a-web-templete-inside-orchard-cms/31767332#31767332) and review what I'm trying to explain. I was very thorough in guiding you trough the process but you really need to -read- and -try- yourself. An experienced Orchard developer is able to create exactly what you want in less then 30 minutes.